# ExplorerBrowserにシェル拡張を適用したい

Tags: c#, winapi

C#でWindows API Code Packの`ExplorerBrowser`を使用しています。

`ExplorerBrowser`の実装を変更し、表示されるファイルに対して

- コンテキストメニューの追加
- プレビューまたはサムネイルの変更

などのシェル拡張をレジストリや他プロセスに影響しない方法で適用することは可能でしょうか。